# I am having 'req.param.id' issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express

I am trying to dynamically load content from this object

```
projects = {
    test1:{
        'name': 'Test',
        'description': 'This is just a test description for a test project.',
        'img': {
            'thumbnail': '/img/260x180.png',
            'screenshot': '/img/1024x500.png'
        },
        'link': '/projects/test1'
     },
    test2:{
        'name': 'Test2',
        'description': 'This is just a test description for a test project.',
        'img': {
            'thumbnail': '/img/260x180.png',
            'screenshot': '/img/1024x500.png'
        },
        'link': '/projects/test2'
     }
    };
```

as follows

```
var id = req.params.id;
res.send('index/project',{title: title, project: projects.id});
```

and it is coming back as undefined. I also tried use JSON.stringify() and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: What's `id`? What's the request URL? What's projects.id? From a JS point of view this doesn't really make too much sense... you're going to have to elaborate on what you want to do if you want help :)

Comment: Beyond the bracket/property issue, I believe that res.send expects two parameters: one, the HTTP status code, and two, the body of the HTTP response. You probably want `res.render('templateName', {title:title})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for bracketed notation:

```
res.send('index/project',{title: title, project: projects[id]});
// Change here ------------------------------------------^^^^
```

In JavaScript, you can access properties of an object either using dot notation and a literal property name (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation and a string property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, of course, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable reference. So assuming `req.params.id` is a string like `"test1"`, `"test2"`, and such, since you're putting that in `id` you'd use `projects[id]` to refer to the `test1` or `test2` properties of `projects`.

Comment: Interesting. It worked perfectly, I just want to make sure I understand why it worked. Is it because when I call 'projects.id' JavaScript is looking for a property and a value to return and when 'projects[id]' is called JavaScript is searching for the string that the id variable is holding

Comment: @CollinMcGuire: `projects.id` looks for a property with the name `id` on the object referenced by `projects`. `projects[id]` looks for a property with the name from the string in the `id` variable on the object referenced by `projects`. E.g., from my example in the answer, these all look up the same property: `obj.foo` | `obj["foo"]` | `obj['f' + 'o' + 'o']` | `var f = "foo"; obj[f]`